# Application of KT?

Tags: computational-physics, physical-chemistry, optimization

I am not familiar with physics and I am lost about how should I actually apply this to the result from the computer simulation.

I would like to apply  to the results of the computational chemistry calculations (found 7 possible structures (local minima) using Monte Carlo search with N steps) in analytical energy function of a molecule (see figure) to see whether the structures are stable/observable at room temp (293 K).

the result is the number of findings (how frequently the structure was found) as a function of the total energy of the structure (plot shows the gaussian smeared density of function).

To answer the question should I convert the 0K simulation energy to K<sub>b</sub>T energy?
or 
For this should I use 'Boltzmann probability distribution'? $$P(s) = \frac{e^\frac{−E(s)}{kT}}{{\Sigma}_se^{\frac{−E(s)} {kT}}}$$

Figure (LM: local minima, GM: global minima): the probability of finding the structure as a function of the total (relative) energy of the structure.

[image: the probability of finding the structure as a function of the relative energy of the structure.]

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking - what is 'number of findings'? It may help to clear up your formatting too - currently this answer writes Boltzmann's constant $k_B$ as $k,kb,kB$, and it is unclear why the last sentence is in a block quote - is this from a textbook or is this your paraphrasing?

Comment: @jacob1729 Apologise for the unclarity. It is hard to ask a question that I don't know well. I have initially searched the energy landscape of a molecule with n searching steps to find possible structures (local minima): found 7 structures. And I want to see whether the structures are observable or still stable in room temp. by plotting similar plot as the above.

Comment: What is the method you are using? There are many methods that boil down to searching the free energy landscape

Comment: @BySymmetry I searched on analytical energy function, not DFT. The question is not about energy landscape searching. I just want to convert this result to room temperature results to check the thermodynamics of the structures.

Comment: The graphic is not matched with the Boltznmann distribution. Otherwise, the 0 energy shoud have the greatest peak.

Comment: @ytlu the plot shows the result from the computational simulation: energy landscape optimisation using Monte Carlo relaxation. I want to convert the simulation result using K<sub>b</sub>t. Could you please give advice for this?

Comment: Is the system a 2-dimention or 3-dimention structure?

Comment: @ytlu they are 3D structure for inorganic nanoclusters

Answer (score 1):

The probability peaks are proportional to the lifetime (or resident time) of the particle staying inside each energy valley. To calculate the life times, first you have to estimate the energy barriers, $E_{a\to b}$ from valley $A$ to one of its directly connected valley $B$. Then apply the transition-state theorem to estimate the transition rate:
$$
    r_{a\to b} = \nu_a \exp{-\frac{E_{a\to b} - E_a}{K_BT}}.
$$
The prefactor $\nu_a$ is the oscillatory frequency of the valley $A$, the number of visiting the barrier within a second roughly speaking.

After you finished all the neighboring sites of each valley, you then write a set of 7 coupled rate eqaution (Master equation):

$$
   \frac{dN_a}{dt} = - \sum_{b=neighbors\, of\, A} r_{a\to b} N_a + \sum_{b=neighbors\, of\, A} r_{b\to a} N_b. \tag{1}
$$
The first term in right-hand-side is the rate of hopping out of site $A$, which decreases the population in site $A$. The second term is the rate of hopping into site $A$ from the neighbors. The index a running $a = 1, 2, 3,...7$. Thus, you established a set of coupled 7 rate equations.

The equilibrium distribition can be obatained by setting the left hand site to zero (the populations no longer changed.):
$$
\frac{dN_a}{dt} = 0,  \text{ for all } a=1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
$$

The right hand side of equation (1) gives you the ratios between all sites. Your may set $N_G$ (the global minimal) to be 1, and calculate the resident number for the rest valleys.

Comment: For a 3-dimension problem, it may be not so obvious to identify the neighbors of each site. And the minimal barrier path ( easy hopping path) probably not easy to find.

Comment: I had experience with 2-dimension problem. For 2-d problem, I made an  energy contour plot to help me determining the hopping contour, and the corresponding hopping barrier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the answer tells how likely we would find the 7 structures in the room temp.? probability of finding the structure at room temp.

Comment: is the oscillatory frequency of a valley mean the width of the energy landscape basin? and for the energy barrier, should I rerun the calculations to find all of the stationary (saddle) points, which is much harder than finding local minima?

Comment: (1) The effect of teamperature is built-in in the  transition rate, higher temperture leads to  larger transition rate, and a flatter distribution. (2) The prefactor is of secondary effect. For simplicity, you may take a reasonable constant rate for all sites, in order of $10^{15} 1/s$ for harder material, and about $10^{13} 1/s$ for soft matter. (3) It is not an easy job, but doable. So it is worthy of trying.